# Load PyQt5 plugin into designer-qt5 (cygwin)

Tags: python-2.7, cygwin, pyqt5, qtplugin

I have recently installed on my cygwin platform the following packages using `apt-cyg`:

> apt-cyg install python-pyqt5
>
> apt-cyg install qt5-devel-tools

The latter command installed Qt Designer as an executable (`designer-qt5`).

PyQt5 examples works fine as well as `pyuic5`.

However, when I download a custom PyQt5 plugin `ledplugin.py` from [here](ftp://ftp.ics.com/pub/pickup/python-designer-plugin.zip), this PyQt5 plugin never loads. I am also setting the environemnt variable:

> export PYQTDESIGNERPATH=.

Lastly, I am using python 2.7 not python 3.x.

Has anybody else encountered this problem? Any solutions?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT (2018/12/18):** I have just tried the pyqt plugins for qt4 (with python 2.7) and it works. My suspicion is that the `libpyqt5.dll` in `/usr/lib/qt5/plugins/designer` does not work properly as `libpyqt4.dll` in `/usr/lib/qt4/plugins/designer` does. Any ideas how to proceed from here?

Comment: You need to show some code how you you are using and any error message.

Comment: The plugin is for python3 as first line is `#!/usr/bin/python3` No surprise does not work with python2

Comment: I have installed `python3-pyqt5` and `python3-sip` and it still does not work. I also changed `python3` to `python2` and it still does not work. I do not think there is any python3-specific syntax inside the plugin.

Comment: "does not work" is not very descriptive. What are you doing ?

Comment: "does not work" means I launch `designer-qt5` and the PyQt plugin does not show up in the widget area on the left (no error messages either). I also tried it with more PyQt plugins and widgets downloaded from the [designer plugin examples](https://github.com/pyqt/examples/tree/master/designer/plugins).